# echo/append a string with multiple double quotes

Tags: sh, double-quotes

I'm processing a text file reading line by line and massaging/filtering the data before writing to another file. Some lines in the original file contain multiple double quotes, others don't:

> Dummy line 'from' a file with ""multiple double"" """quotes""" and single double "quotes".

I want to preserve all those weird quotes, basically treat the whole line as raw data. However, currently my approach removes all instances of double quotes

```
while read -r line
do
    # do some filtering
    echo "$line">> $ebooks ;;
done < $filename
```

I assume sed can help with that, but it seems that even if I insert sed substitution after echo "$line", echo would already have already removed all quotes. How to apply sed without echo or what is a good approach for such issues?

Please, POSIX compliant only (sh) solutions, no bash/zsh/csh/etc.

Comment: its' the `echo` that is messing  you up. Process your file exclusively with `sed` and you should be ok. Good luck.

Comment: How can I use sed without piping echoed result into it?

Comment: `sed 's/string/replacment/' file > outFile && mv outFile file` OR if you using a newer sed, use `sed -i 's/string/replacement/' file` Good luck.

Comment: I'm not dealing with a file here, I have lines of text, some of which I want to skip, some to modify in different manners, others leave intact and I want to do all that in one pass and without storing the file in memory. I feel like bash is not the right tool for my task; after spending 5 hours googling, decided to go with python.

Comment: what do you thing `while read -r line ; do .... ; done < $filename` is doing? Sed can easily skip lines by number, range, or reg-ex pattern or reg-ex range. (It is not right for every situation). Include sample input with data that needs to be changed and some that shouldn't be changed and the show your required output and you'll have an answer in 1 hr or less. (I;m going out for the evening, but will check back later). Good luck.